# RDL Reports with MVC3 (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssrs-2008

I am working on a MVC 3 (Razor) application where in I am using RDL (SSRS) for reporting. My requirement is to allow users to select multiple records using Checkbox & when they click on the print button, the PDF should be generated & printed for the selected records. The PDFs are generating using RDL Reports. I am not sure that how to call the aspx page containing the report viewer control.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use WebForms (thus mixing WebForms and MVC) in order to use the aspx with the report viewer control.
You can find more information on how to do it [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: I am not sure how to return the data from web form to MVC view. I am generating a pdf file using RDL report on webform & now want to provide users the options to save the PDF generated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't the webform itself give the user the opportunity to save the report as a PDF?